# Windows 10 locked in automatic repair but no administrator account

Tags: windows-10, administrator, repair

My notebook was shut down and entered automatic repair. But when it loaded it requested an administrator account, which it resolved it was non existent. Nevertheless I had already registered and activated an administrator account using the following command:

net user administrator /active:yes

I guess it should turn the admin on, but it didn't. Does anyone know how can I login and repair my Windows?

Comment: I am not sure the reason your attempting to enable the built-in Administrator account but if you are then it's a duplicate of that question

Comment: I am not trying to enable it. It IS enabled. Butbthe automatic repair doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Go through my answer and verify then update your question.  Still not sure, why you enabled it, Windows attempting to automatically repair itself indicates severe system corruption problems